# Подскажите софт для MySQL, который построит граф связей между таблицами

Tags: mysql

Есть ли софт для MySQL, который сам может построить граф связей между таблицами базы данных?

Должен ли тогда у всех таблиц присутствовать внешний ключ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-mysql) умеет создавать делать диаграммы по существующей схеме и наоборот. FK не обязаны быть, но если они заданы, то попадут на ER диаграмму при импорте.

[image: Navicat ER diagram]

Comment: Получается, что все связи нужно на ER-диаграмме самим вручную добавлять?

Comment: Если их *нет в базе*, то да. Программа за вас решать не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Для построения графов есть [mysql workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) или [phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/).
Внешний ключ не обязательно, но рекомендовано чтобы был.

Comment: Как интересно софт нарисует граф если не будет внешних ключей. Это же единственно на что он может ориентироваться при рисовании связи

Comment: @mike будет нарисовано отдельно стоящая таблица, без связи.

Answer (score 0):

Есть [продукт от devart](https://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/mysql/studio/).
С его помощью не только сможете построить графы, но и можете сравнить, анализировать и .т д схемы